# Laravel unable to add new package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am unable to add new package in laravel project. I am using laravel 7.2
I was trying to run this command

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

but i got below error.

```
    Problem 1
        - Root composer.json requires kreait/laravel-firebase ^3.0, 
found kreait/laravel-firebase[3.0.0] 
but the package is fixed to 2.2.0 (lock file version) 
by a partial update and that version does not match. 
Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades,
downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

I also tried composer update but still getting this error.

Comment: Try to run `composer update` first then install the package.

Comment: I have already written that "I also tried composer update but still getting this error."

Comment: Please share more details, like the current state of your `composer.json`

Comment: I have accepted answer which resolved the issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I can see, your `composer.json` file has an outdated version of `kreait/laravel-firebase` package. `stripe/stripe-php` requires `kreait/laravel-firebase` version that is > `3.0` & your version is `3.0.0`. Change the version of the `kreait/laravel-firebase` in your `composer.json`, then delete `composer.lock` file, and then `composer install` again. That way, all your packages will be updated to the new specified version. Without deleting `composer.lock` file, composer would only install cached versions of your packages, even if you change the versions.

Comment: I simply deleted the composer.lock and then installed the package version with : composer require package/sth  "version" --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: --ignore-platform-reqs worked for me when I had an issue with a package specifying a version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your composer.json file according to the error package version, In your case change from `kreait/laravel-firebase ^3.0` to `kreait/laravel-firebase ^3.0.0` Then Delete `composer.lock` file and run `composer install` command. Hopefully it will fix your problem.

Comment: You say to change the version, but what you say to change it to is the same as the original.

Comment: @cs1349459 ah, my bad. Fixed now

Answer (score -4):

Just delete the `composer.json` and `composer install` everything will be fixed.

Comment: You probably meant: just delete `composer.lock` (so the lock file, not json file), as this would work.